# SQL- Looking for a value in a query in another table and return YES/NO

Tags: sql

[image]I have a sql code, wherein I am trying to look for whether the fundsrc against the project has a relation in another table. If the relation is there, then it should just give Yes, else NO.

So basically, what's happening in my case is, it is looking for the project (t.dim_1) in the table aglrelvalue and looks for its relation (rel_value) which is fundsrc and if the rel_value is same as the fundsrc (t.dim_6), then it should return YES else NO. The issue is, the result is returning YES/NO for all the matching/unmatching values of Project.
Ideally, the project should be checked in the complete list, and if there are 10 fundsrc, and none match, then it should just say NO only once and not 10 times.

```
select sum(t.amount) as amount, t.dim_6 as fundsrc ,t.dim_1 as project,
CASE WHEN d5.rel_value = t.dim_6 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS projrel

FROM  agltransact t 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN atsproject p on p.client ='PC' and p.project = t.dim_1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN aglrelvalue  d5  ON d5.client =  'PC'  and d5.rel_attr_id='ZB18' and t.dim_1 = d5.att_value

where t.period between '201801 ' and '202004' 
and t.dim_6 LIKE 'AWD-000261' 
 and t.client ='PC'
 group by t.dim_6,t.dim_1,t.client,d5.rel_value
 order by t.dim_1
```

Comment: Sample data and expected result would help. Please tag your database too.

Comment: Shouldn't `d5.client =  'PC'  and d5.rel_attr_id='ZB18'` be in WHERE clause? Already have filter criteria for `'PC'`. LIKE without a wildcard might as well be = sign.

Comment: @June7, et. al., The OP has provided the requested clarity, so please vote to reopen so that I can post the answer.

Comment: Requested data sample not provided but answers have been possible with less info than this question has so voted to reopen.

Comment: Well tired of waiting.  I will have to post it in the answer here in the comments ...

Comment: Often cases where you are receiveing multiple rows when you want only one row are because you are using a JOIN when you really need a subquery instead.

This should work: ...

Comment: select sum(t.amount) as amount, t.dim_6 as fundsrc ,t.dim_1 as project,
    CASE WHEN t.dim_6 IN(Select d5.rel_value  From aglrelvalue  d5  
                  WHERE d5.client = 'PC' 
                           and d5.rel_attr_id='ZB18' 
                           and t.dim_1 = d5.att_value)
         THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS projrel
FROM  agltransact t 
LEFT OUTER JOIN atsproject p on p.client ='PC' and p.project = t.dim_1
where t.period between '201801 ' and '202004' 
  and t.dim_6 LIKE 'AWD-000261' 
  and t.client ='PC'
group by t.dim_6,t.dim_1,t.client
order by t.dim_1

Comment: apologies for the delay as I am based in a different time zone.

Comment: Please check the image that I have added which makes should make clear what is expected out of the query.

Comment: @RBarryYoung, it's reopened so you can create answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often cases where you are receiving multiple rows when you want only one row are because you are using a JOIN when you really need a subquery instead.

I believe that something like the following should work:

```
select sum(t.amount) as amount, t.dim_6 as fundsrc ,t.dim_1 as project, 
    CASE WHEN t.dim_6 IN(Select d5.rel_value From aglrelvalue d5 
                         WHERE d5.client = 'PC'
                           and d5.rel_attr_id='ZB18' 
                           and t.dim_1 = d5.att_value) 
         THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS projrel 
FROM agltransact t 
LEFT OUTER JOIN atsproject p on p.client ='PC' and p.project = t.dim_1 
where t.period between '201801 ' and '202004' 
  and t.dim_6 LIKE 'AWD-000261' 
  and t.client ='PC' 
group by t.dim_6,t.dim_1,t.client 
order by t.dim_1
```

Comment: thank you RBarryYoung. I think this is what I was looking for. Will having EXIST instead of IN make a any difference in the case statement?

Comment: @SugandhaSharma In most cases they are the same: EXIST treats NULLs slightly differently but that usually only comes up in the negative (i.e., NOT EXISTS(..) vs. NOT IN(..) ).  EXISTS is usually considered better as it's slightly more general and sometimes can be faster, but EXISTS is also slightly more complicated to write because you have to add the external matching condition (`WHEN t.dim_6 IN(Select d5.rel_value`) into the subqueries WHERE clause ((`WHERE t.dim_6 = d5.rel_value AND ...`) ), but that should be easy in this case.